# Is there a way we can use substitution without using gsub or sub option available in awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

## I have a file .sh invoking test.awk to do the substitution

**.sh**

```
 read_input (){
        read name
        read house
        read phone
        } < $file

export name;phone;house

awk test.awk $template.txt
```

## This is just an example of the template but it is similar

**template.txt**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>PAST DUE NOTICE - APT (House) - (date)></h1>
        <p>
            Dear (Name),
        </p>
        <p>
           Your phone number(Phone) is violating our policy 
        </p>
        <p>
           Address: (House)
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.awk**

```
{gsub ("(Name)",ENVIRON ["name"]);
gsub ("(House)",ENVIRON["house"]);
gsub ("(Phone)",ENVIRON["phone"]);}
```

Comment: Can you show template.txt? I think it has fields like `(Name)` that needs to be replaced by `${name}`.

Comment: You have to export like `export name phone house`, or you'll only export `name` and then try to run commands `phone` and `house`.

Comment: I did export variables check out .sh code block

Comment: You separated them with semicolons, which ends the export after `name`.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah somehow it worked on mine.

Comment: What is the problem you're having that makes you think you need to avoid [g]sub()? Right now this is an XY Question.

Answer (score 0):

If the object of the exercise is to demonstrate that you can substitute text using **`awk`** ***without*** **`sub`**/**`gsub`**, you could use **`substr`** and **`index`** to chop up strings and put them together.  That's more work, of course.